# How can I search for the newest result with arguments, regarding no duplicate by condition and sum this

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

There is a possibility to enter numerical values in a table, suitable for group and name, with information of the range, and a numerical value (zw), with this it should be indicated, who has when how many places available.

| timestamp | group | name | zw | r_start | r_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:01 | Group1 | Player1 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:02 | Group2 | Player2 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:03 | Group1 | Player3 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:04 | Group1 | Player1 | 40 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:05 | Group1 | Player3 | 50 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:06 | Group1 | Player1 | 20 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 0:00:07 | Group1 | Player3 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:01 | Group1 | Player1 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:02 | Group2 | Player2 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:03 | Group1 | Player3 | 30 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:04 | Group1 | Player1 | 40 | 01/12/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:05 | Group1 | Player3 | 50 | 01/12/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:06 | Group1 | Player1 | 20 | 01/01/2022 | 01/20/2022 |
| 01/02/2022 0:00:07 | Group1 | Player3 | 30 | 01/08/2022 | 01/20/2022 |

I want the numerical value, added, of group1 from 01/03/2022.

How do I get the numerical value "zw" of group 1 added so that always only the newest numerical value (zw) to the player of the day (timestamp) is considered, and the searched date fits into the range "r_start" - "r_end"?

The result here is: 100

Is there a possibility, for example if you have the list of players matching the group, to process the players dynamically in a formula, for example, a query formula, which normally could give you the numerical value (zw) fitting to the tag, isolated with limit/offset etc, but now in a loop with the name and team as dynamic criteria?

Maybe something faster than the query formula?

A formula that can take one or more arrays as criterion, and this formula repeats itself as long as the array has places, and can read a certain list, focus on a column, and for example add the newest entry.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected result?

Comment: " something faster than the query formula?" what is ur current runtime record ? (for benchmark)  | "always only the newest " -->> = max(<time>)

Comment: @Sheet N00B welcome!  what have you done so far to achieve the desired outcome? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)